# useState and checkbox wrong state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I know this topic has been discussed many times and I have already tried a few things.

Initially the checkbox is not checked, which is correct. At the first click `hasTableHeader` is still `false` and only at the second click `hasTableHeader` changes the state to `true`, which is wrong, because the input then is unchecked. I would be very grateful for any hints.

```
import  React, { useState } from 'react';
const [hasTableHeader, setHasTableHeader] = useState(false);

const handleHeaderChange = () => {
    setHasTableHeader(!hasTableHeader)
}

return (
  ...
   <input type="checkbox" checked={hasTableHeader} onChange={handleHeaderChange}/>
  ...
 )
```

Comment: you need to wrap that code into a function, aka react component function. that is not a working code example.

Comment: your code is fine and should work as expected, can you provide the whole component ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change state to opposite of current boolean state in react you can try :

**Functional component**

```
setHasTableHeader(prev=>!prev)
```

**Class component**

```
this.setState({
   hasTableHeader : !this.state.hasTableHeader
})
```

In your case the code you're looking for here :

```
import React , {useState} from 'react'

export default function CheckboxComponent() {
  const [hasTableHeader, setHasTableHeader] = useState(false);

  const handleHeaderChange = () => {
    setHasTableHeader(prev=>!prev)
  }

  return (
     <input type="checkbox" checked={hasTableHeader} onChange={handleHeaderChange} />
  )
}
```

You can use this component anywhere like this :

```
import CheckboxComponent from './CheckboxComponent'

<CheckboxComponent />
```

Comment: thx! I've tried to use the functional component but it shows the same behavior

Comment: @mm1975 I've added more info to the answer and the full working code .

Comment: there is no difference between `setHasTableHeader(prev=>!prev)` and `setHasTableHeader(!hasTableHeader)` in the example above

Answer (score 0):

works fine as react function component for me:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function MyCheckBox() {
  const [hasTableHeader, setHasTableHeader] = useState(false);
  const handleHeaderChange = () => {
    setHasTableHeader(!hasTableHeader)
  }

  return (
     <input type="checkbox" checked={hasTableHeader} onChange={handleHeaderChange}/>
   )
}
```

can then be used somewhere else like this: `<MyCheckBox/>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is somewhere else, because code is correct.

```js
const { useState } = React;


const App = () => {
  const [hasTableHeader, setHasTableHeader] = useState(false);

  const handleHeaderChange = () => {
    setHasTableHeader(!hasTableHeader)
  }
  
  return (
    <input type="checkbox" checked={hasTableHeader} onChange={handleHeaderChange} /> 
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```